# Best table design for lot tracking

Tags: sql

I would like to design a table to help track the contents of a tank over time.  The tank is typically filled all at once, and a lot name will be applied to it, and it will be emptied. If this is the only scenario then I would do this.

Table: dye_tank

```
dye_id (PK)
dye_lot
dye_color
```

Table: paint

```
paint_id (PK)
paint_lot
paint_color
```

Table: dye_transfer

```
dye_transfer_id(PK)
dye_id (FK)
paint_id (FK)
dye_transfer_note
```

This would allow me to transfer multiple lots of dye into one tank of paint, and use one tank of dye between multiple lots of paint.

What if I would ALSO like to be able to transfer a lot of paint into another lot of paint. For example, I could add yellow dye to a paint tank to make a lot of yellow paint, then pump that into an existing batch of blue, to make a new batch of green paint. Do you recommend a separate table for lot transfers like:

Table:paint_transfer

```
paint_transfer_id (PK)
paint_id (FK)
paint_id (FK)
```

or is there a better solution. I could expand the dye transfer table and make it:

Table:transfer

```
transfer_id (PK)
source_id
source_type
paint_id (FK)
transfer_note
```

With this I could set the source type to either be 'paint' or 'dye' and set the source_id to be the appropriate PK of the source ingredient. One disadvantage of this is I would have to use some more complex triggers and not rely of the built-in foreign key cascades to maintain referential integrity.

The first solution seems simpler, but the second seems like it would allow for more flexibility going forward.

A third solution would be to ignore the fact the a paint tank-to-tank transfer occurred and just record the "Green" tank creation as a transfer of all the lots from the yellow tank and all the lots from the green tank.

Can anyone see specific advantages or disadvantages to either solution, or used something different for a similar problem?

Comment: why use such small column names.  dye_id, paint_id, transfer_id are much easier to understand and read.  there is no effect on performance of having column names that people can understand.

Comment: I would recommend two tables for the two transfer types unless you expect there to be many different types of transfers.  With just two types two tables is better.  With 4 or more a more generic system would be better.  You can always make a view of the combined tables if you feel a need for data in that format.

Comment: When editing the column names, I also added a third option...ignore tank transfer and just record the new paint as a new collection of dye transfers. I'm not ~really~ making paint, but the analogy works well, and trying to see what's worked well for others

Comment: And I've never made paint but I have an answer, if you are doing less than 4 types of actions -- different tables -- if you have more or *might* have more than 4 then make a generic action description extension to your model.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it would be to think of this like a bill of materials.  Each tank has a mixture of lots of different types of materials.  So something like this:

```
Table: tank
tank_id (PK)

Table: material
material_id (PK)
material_class (paint, dye, anything else...)
material_color

Table: material_lot
lot_id (PK)
material_id

Table tank_contents
tank_id (PK)
lot_id (PK)
transfer_note

Table tank_contents_history
date_emptied (PK)
tank_id (PK)
lot_id (PK)
transfer_note
```

When filling a tank, you add the lots to `tank_contents`.  When it's empty you remove the lots and add them to `tank_contents_history`.  To find the color of a tank, you would have to run a query to calculate what the combination of colors of materials in the tank would make.

You don't have quantities on your lots... so that might make it difficult to calculate the color.  But maybe this model is trying to fit too tightly to the analogy than your reality.

Comment: This would be good for a "current snapshot", but if, six month from now, we want to know what went ingredients went into lot 150911, there would be no record. Lot tracking is used for situations where, say, a vendor performed a recall of a lot of dye, you would want to know all the lots of paint in the marketplace which would be affected. In the opposite direction, if you notice a quality issue with a lot of paint, you can backtrack to all the raw materials to try to identify which may be the source of the problem.

Comment: Easy to fix... just move tank contents to an archive table instead of deleting it.

Comment: Added to my answer to detail what I mean.